# How to change the position of an element in Stackpanel?

Tags: wpf

I have a Stackpanel with 5 child .

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock >1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >3</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >4</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >5</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

I want change the position of child[2].

How do change the position of an element in runtime?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the position"? Do you want to reorder the items or move them on the screen?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: i want change position of two element for example i want change position of textblock 1,4

Answer (score 4):

It can be achieved by keeping track of the index-element of the Children-property of the StackPanel. I send you some sample code that demonstrates the working of this. For instance, consider the following code:

```
    int currentSelectedIndex = stackPanel1.Children.IndexOf(CurrentSelectedTextBlock);
    int downIndex = currentSelectedIndex + 1;
    int childCount = stackPanel1.Children.Count;
    if (downIndex < childCount)
    {
        stackPanel1.Children.RemoveAt(currentSelectedIndex);
        stackPanel1.Children.Insert(downIndex, CurrentSelectedTextBlock);
    }
    else if (downIndex == childCount)
    {
        stackPanel1.Children.RemoveAt(currentSelectedIndex);
        stackPanel1.Children.Insert(currentSelectedIndex, CurrentSelectedTextBlock);
    }
```

It gets the currently-selected TextBlock and moves its index up one higher. You then need to update the Children-property of the StackPanel by removing and inserting it back again.

I question whether you want to use a StackPanel for this type of purpose. It's much easier to use an ItemsControl, like a ListBox as they can be bound to a ObservableCollection of T. Once the bound collection is updated, the control is updated likewise.

I hope this helps. The sample code can be download [here](http://sdrv.ms/X7A2ZR).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Children.Insert` method to insert an Element into a slot of your `StackPanel`.

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
Image newElement = new Image();

// Add UIElements to StackPanel
stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Element 1" });
stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Element 2" });
stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Element 3" });

// Insert Grid as the first element in StackPanel
stackPanel.Children.Insert(0, newElement);
```

Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.insert?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat unclear as the intention is not laid out very specific. The following code allows you to move a TextBlock based upon the Text-content-property:

```
        string number = "4";
    TextBlock textBlockToSearch = null;

    foreach (var child in stackPanel1.Children)
    {
        if (child is TextBlock)
        {
            var textBlock = (TextBlock) child;
            if (textBlock.Text.CompareTo(number) == 0)
                textBlockToSearch = textBlock;
        }
    }

    if (textBlockToSearch != null)
    {
        stackPanel1.Children.Remove(textBlockToSearch);
        int pos = 2;
        stackPanel1.Children.Insert(pos - 1, textBlockToSearch);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Could not find TextBlock");
    }
```

If you have other intentions, like using your mouse once selecting the TextBlock, you may need to use different techniques, like seen in the Visual Studio-interface at design-time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, Is there any other way without remove element and insert again , for change position two element?

Comment: I'm not sure. According to the MSDN-documentation, "The layout queue is sorted based upon the order of elements in the visual tree. Elements higher in the tree are at the top of the queue..." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx. I wouldn't use the Content-property as to identify the TextBlock, but a unique identifier like the Name-property. If you want to go in depth on this I suggest you do some more research.